# Drupal 7 taxonomy filters

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I want to create filters with taxonomy filters. Now, I have one filter for one taxonomie list. But I want to add another taxonomy filter next to it. For example: a filter for the place they live. I already added the taxonomy list. How is this possible?

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are really trying to accomplish here. You want to add multiple select list filter on various vocabularies?

If this is it, have you tried the filter: 'Taxonomy term: Term' in Views. When you select it, you can choose which vocabulary you want to display in the list. And you can repeat the operation as many time as you need.

I hope it works!